# How do i check if a known hidden SSID network is in range or not?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, ssid

Consider i have an configured router with known hidden SSID named "hiddenhotspot" and i just want to check if it is in range in my android application.

As i know the scanned results of WifiManager doesn't return hidden networks. So is there any way that i can ensure my desired wifi is in range or not?

Answer (score 1):

first understand Access point ssends out a broadcasting request or announcing it's self that i am SSID abc and i use security but when you make SSID hidden then those broadcast don't have SSID in that so you never find

You can't scan a hidden wifi SSID so you also never find a hidden wifi is in range or not

note: if you know the hidden SSID so you can mannually connect the wifi. (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: there arte apps who find  hiiden ssids